# Ruby program Kaprekar number test

Tags: ruby, math, sequences

I'm trying to make a bit of code which will test whether or not a number is a Kaprekar number. I looked around to see if someone had already brought this up, but I didn't find sufficient information, so I'm bringing my woes to you.

What a Kaprekar number is:

For a Kaprekar number k with n-digits, if you square it and add the right n digits to the left n or n-1 digits, the resultant sum is k. 9 is an example of this, since 9^2=81, and 8+1=9.

Here's what I've got put together right now:

```
def kaprekar?(k)

  if k**2.to_s.length % 2 == 0
    split_k_array = k**2.to_s.split(//)
    half_k_array_length = split_k_array.length / 2
    i = half_k_array_length
    x1 = 0

    while i > 0
      x1 = x1 + (10**i * split_k_array[i-1])
      i = i - 1
    end

    x2 = 0
    i = split_k_array.length

    while i > half_k_array_length
      x2 = x2 + (10**(i-half_k_array_length))
      i = i - 1
    end

    if k == x1 + x2
      return true
    else
      return false
    end

  else

    puts "Let's figure out what wrong with the other code first :("
    return "Meh"

  end

end

if kaprekar(500500)
  puts "500500 is True :)"
else
  puts "500500 is False :("
end

if kaprekar(9)
  puts "9 is True :)"
else
  puts "9 is False :("
end
```

if kaprekar(22)
  puts "22 is True"
else
  puts "22 is False"
end

This code is not returning any errors, but as long as the square of k is an even number of digits long, whether the number provided is a Kaprekar number or not, the method returns the value True. In fact, even if I change the test portion to:

```
if x1 + x2 = k
  return false
else
  return false
end
```

...I still get True returned to me! How is that possible?

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT 1: I fixed the truth assignments to read "==" instead of "=", and I changed the "^" exponents to "**". However, I'm still getting "True" returned to me in both of the circumstances I described above. :(

EDIT 2: Seems I missed 2 "^"s! Fixed it!

EDIT 3: added some code to test the Kaprekar method each time the code is run. Fixed the error on line (Seems like I was trying to split the length of a string, rather that the string itself. Gosh!). In any case, now I'm getting the error message: "kaprekarTest.rb:37: undefined method `kaprekar' for main:Object (NoMethodError)" Now, I just defined the kaprekar method. why should I get an error saying that there is no such method?

Comment: No, you haven't fixed the ^ statement yet.  Line 2 for example.

Comment: Sorry about that! I had fixed the ones at the bottom, but missed the ones at the top. Thank you for taking the time. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Now you should take care of all the other errors.  For example: "NoMethodError
 undefined method `split' for 1:Fixnum"  From line 3.

Comment: I fixed that error. Now I'm getting a new error (see edit 3)

Comment: Read your error message.  Obviously you have some code where you are calling a method called `kaprekar` and you don't have a method with that name.  What I do see is a method called `kaprekar?` and that is a whole other animal.  You need to write your code out, until you have something you are mostly happy to show.  So far, everything we have addressed has nothing really to do with your number tests, but with Ruby.  Also fix your code block, you have a line directly below the highlighting that I think you really want in that code block.

Comment: I've tried it both with and without the question mark. I'd like to be happy with the code, really. I think the way I handled it, conceptually speaking, is kind of clever. I just do not understand why it's jamming up. Also, I only got my hands on a proper Ruby compiler that returns error messages an hour before my last post. ^_^; In any case, thanks so much for you time! I'm sure that I'll get to the bottom of this some way or other

Comment: I nor anyone else, will likely attempt to answer this until all obvious runtime errors are taken care of, such as calling a method that simply doesn't exist, trying to split numbers, and trying to multiply a number by a string.  After those are fixed, then I think we can attack the logic errors.

Answer (score 3):

the best and simple solution to find the kaprekar Number:

```
def kaprekar?(k)
  ks = k**2
  lenf = (ks.to_s.length)-1
  lenh = (ks.to_s.length / 2) - 1
  a = ks.to_s[0..lenh].to_i
  b = ks.to_s[lenh+1..lenf].to_i
  k == (a+b)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

^ isn't pow in Ruby.  ** is.

```
> 3^2
=> 1
> 3**2
=> 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Silly me. Yikes! I'll correct for this and I'll let you know if it works. :)

Comment: I applied both your and vgoff's fixes, but I'm still getting the same results. All "truth" all the time. :S

Comment: Posted the updated code. I guess I missed two instances of "^" before. Sorry about that. :|

Thanks for noticing! Sadly, fixing the remaining carets didn't fix my "return truth no matter what problem."

Thanks so much for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

```
if x1 + x2 = k
```

That is an assignment statement, not a conditional statement and as such it will always be 'truthy'.

And as Philip has stated the "exponential operator" is `**` rather than `^`.

**Update:** You are calling (as I mentioned earlier) a method that doesn't exist when you call `if kaprekar(500500)` because you defined `keprekar?` method.

In your method, you probably will need to enclose `k**2` in parenthesis, so that the `.to_s` call is not only acting on the number 2.

After these fixes, hopefully you will fix the remainder of the errors being raised, so at least we can get to the point were we can 'figure out what's wrong with the other code first'.

This code will get you answers.  Not verified for the actual correctness of those numbers, but at least not getting syntax or runtime errors.

```
def kaprekar(k)

  if k**2.to_s.length % 2 == 0
    split_k_array = (k**2).to_s.split(//)
    half_k_array_length = split_k_array.length / 2
    i = half_k_array_length
    x1 = 0

    while i > 0
      x1 = x1 + ((10**i) * split_k_array[i-1].to_f)
      i = i - 1
    end

    x2 = 0
    i = split_k_array.length

    while i > half_k_array_length
      x2 = x2 + (10**(i-half_k_array_length))
      i = i - 1
    end

    if k == x1 + x2
      return true
    else
      return false
    end

  else

  end

end

if kaprekar(500500)
  puts "500500 is True :)"
else
  puts "500500 is False :("
end

if kaprekar(9)
  puts "9 is True :)"
else
  puts "9 is False :("
end
```

Comment: Alright. I'm gonna go correct my code using your advice. I'll be back!

Comment: Alright, I fixed what both of you mentioned, but I'm still getting the results I described in the original question. :(

Are there any other reasons why my if/else statement would have no say in whether I get a "truth" response or not?

Answer (score 0):

KAPREKAR

```
def convert_array(number)
  arr = []
  div = 10**(number.to_s.length - 1)

  while div >= 10 do
    arr << (number/div)
    number = (number%div)
    div = (div / 10)
  end

  arr << number
  arr
end

def kaprekar?(number)
  c = convert_array(number**2)
  i = 0
  flag = false

  while i < c.length do
    if number == (c.first(i).join().to_i + c.last(c.length - i).join().to_i)
      flag = true
      break
    end

    i = i+1
  end

  flag
end
```

Try this.

Answer (score -1):

In case you want to make it more concise:

```
def kaprekar?(k)
  k_squared = (k*k).to_s
  idx = k_squared.length / 2
  return k_squared[0..idx-1].to_i + k_squared[idx..-1].to_i == k
end
```

As a side note: I would love to see if somebody comes up with a **faster** ruby implementation?

```
require 'benchmark'
puts Benchmark.measure{ (1..10000000).select{|k| kaprekar?(k)} }
```

yields

```
ruby kaprekar.rb
11.240000   0.010000  11.250000 ( 11.249131)
```

on my machine.

Edit: posted shorter version of solution